# Redirect using javascript or CSS on device rotation from portrait/landscape

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css, iphone

I searched for a possible answer to this problem but not much fun at all so far. So maybe you can help; I designed a mobile version for a website and can easily target/redirect to this version from the main desktop layout using this:

```
 // load Mobile version
  if (screen.width <= 999) {
window.location = "http://www.domain/test/Mobile/index.html";
```

}

Works fine when accessing the website on small devices; (iPhones, Androids in portrait & landscape) or tablets (iPads, Kindles, Androids in portrait).

Now I would like to go back to the desktop layout when the tablets (with a: (screen.width >= 1000)) are accessing the website in landscape.

So when in portrait mode (keep the mobile version layout), then when rotated redirect (to the desktop version) better suited to view in landscape.

How best to achieve this, knowing that my coding is limited tho;-) or if there's already an answer for this please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, using jQuery mobile [(more info here)](https://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/) like proposed by @Felipe_Valencia:

```
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
       //Don't forget to include these ^
<script>
    $( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
      if (event.orientation == 'landscape' && screen.width>=1000){
          // load landscape version
          window.location = "http://www.domain/test/index.html";
      }
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

---

There's also an Ipad only solution.
This script detects mobile browsers but I have removed the part, where it detects iPads. Check it out for yourself:

```
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
<script src="code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script> 
<script>
//Don't forget to include these ^ 
$( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) { 
    if (event.orientation == 'landscape'){ 
         // load landscape version if not mobile browser (except the ipad one) 
          if(!(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ) {
              window.location = "http://www.domain/test/index.html";
          };
    };
});
</script>
```

Hope it helped :)

Comment: Thanks @Evochrome for your help, but so far no luck! I can get the mobile version in the devices (portrait & landscape) and the desktop on larger screens as planned. But it doesn't work when orientated in landscape using a tablet (ipad & kindle Fire HD). Both are fine in portrait but doesn't switch back to the desktop layout when in landscape.

Comment: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// load Mobile version
   if (screen.width <= 999) {
    window.location = "http://www.example/Mobile/index.html";
  }
  $( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
  if (event.orientation == 'landscape' && screen.width>=1000){
      // load landscape version
      window.location = "http://www.example/index.html";
  }}); `
   This is my code but doesn't work. Let me know if you can spot a problem. Thx!

Comment: What if you try without '&& screen.width>=1000'?

Comment: thanks for your tips! it worked somehow, but also more worrying issues surged! With a kindle Fire HD 8.9 I was able to go from mobile version portrait to landscape desktop version when rotated (strange also I was able to test it with the dev tool in FF & Chrome, but it did not worked live on iPad Mini). But the bigger problem now; I lost my navigation on both (mobile/desktop, on phones or tablets)!!! Worse; it got stuck "loading" the pages when clicking the navigation...forever. Not sure why this is happening tho. If you could point to something that would be appreciated. Thx.

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with the code above (the loading part) :(

Comment: yeah that's what I am thinking too, but why this is happening...I will have to go another route to avoid that.

Comment: Hi @Evochrome. I think that the problems I encontered are due to clashes with jquery versions, or the fact that I don't use jquery mobile at all for this website. By reversing to my previous work, and using the simple JavaScript redirect I was able to load the landscape version when rotated (a click on the refresh was required tho to load the correct layout). So I think your answer is working but if the website is entirely done using jquery mobile. I have other questions but will search 1st in case I found a similar answer already available. Thanks for your help (all who did answer). Many thx!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback,I think you're right, I have tested it myself and it did actually work for me. It's a pity that it doesn't work for you, though. If you could mark my answer as the right answer, so other people that search for this can benefit from this, that'd be great :)

Comment: Thanks @Evochrome, I have to say that I would love to make it work but I am pretty limited in JS and then find out why things are not working is a problem for me. Now I wonder if the same script could do this: with the iPad from portrait to landscape on rotation to load another css file to target just the landscape iPad. In fact not to use the mobile css version but the desktop version. The Androids devices are swapping without problems, but the iPad can't (css for width over 1000px is not applied). I hope I make sense. How to force it to do as the Androids devices??

Comment: `<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
       //Don't forget to include these ^
$( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
  if (event.orientation == 'landscape'){
      // load landscape version if not mobile browser (except the ipad one)
 if(!(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ) {window.location = "http://www.domain/test/index.html";)}
  };` Please try this once, this should only work for ipad

Comment: Also make sure the code itself is between script tags but the external js outside! And only include one version of the 'normal jQuery' and one version of jQuery mobile. Let me know how it went :)

Comment: Ps. I just saw I had a typing mismatch in my original code, could you try it again?

Comment: Thanks @Evochrome I tried your code and it did not work, not sure why because by looking at it again it's pretty simple and should work. But then  again I was not able to swap to the "desktop layout" when in landscape. I returned to my old script and it's fine again, but for the ipad not loading the desktop layout when rotated in landscape (using FF & Chrome Dev Tools my script work fine, but not when test live with an iPad Mini!!!).

Comment: Hi Evochrome, hope you're there, still struggling with this ipad redirection/orientation stuff. This is beyond me why the Androids can do it and not the ipads? Also the jQuery.mobile is not good for me either. I am looking for a JS only method maybe, because from landscape to portrait is fine, the other way portrait to landscape is not working (but only on iPads). I tried many things with JS found online but nothing. If you have another minute check this link: http://www.totoetco.net/New_PFS_F1/index.html to see for yourself (if you have an iPad try it as well as with a large screen). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.matchMedia

```
function redirectMobile() {
    if (typeof window.matchMedia !== "undefined" && window.matchMedia("(max-width: 999px)").matches) {
        window.location = "http://www.domain/test/Mobile/index.html";
    }
}
```

// you can extend with forexample "(orientation: landscape)" or other media queries for other types of redirects.

Comment: Hi LochNess I will try your answer as well and will send you the results. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you use JQuery mobile, you can try something like this...

```
$( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
   $( "#orientation" ).text( "This device is in " + event.orientation + " mode!" );
    if ($(window).width() <= 999) {
        window.location = "http://www.domain/test/Mobile/index.html";
    }
});
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Hi Felipe thanks for your answer, I will try it but want to know if I place the code in a separate .js link?

Comment: Just add  code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js and put the code below, with the <script> tags